# Can not use ICUTokenizerFactory in Solr

Tags: solr, lucene, schema, tokenize, analyzer

I am trying to use ICUTokenizerFactory in Solr schema. This is how I have defined `field` and `fieldType`.

```
<fieldType name="text_icu" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.ICUTokenizerFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>

<field name="fld_icu" type="text_icu" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

And, when I start Solr, I am get this error

```
Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] fieldType "text_icu": Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] analyzer/tokenizer: Error loading class 'solr.ICUTokenizerFactory'
```

I have searched in for that with no success. I don't know if I am missing something or there is some problem in schema.
If someone has tried ICUTokenizerFactory then please suggest what could be the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the Wiki:

> Lucene provides support for segmenting these languages into syllables with solr.ICUTokenizerFactory in the analysis-extras contrib module. To use this tokenizer, see solr/contrib/analysis-extras/README.txt for instructions on which jars you need to add to your SOLR_HOME/lib

Comment: The README.txt is not clearly showing what to do, I tried keeping the jars into SOLR_HOME/lib, however, the error remains the same.

Comment: You need to put solr-analysis-extras.*.jar from dist and all jars in contrib/analysis-extras/lib in SOLR_HOME/lib. If you use Tomcat put it in WEB-INF/lib.

Comment: Could you help me with one more thing, whats the difference between CJK and ICU tokenizers?

Comment: CJk is for Chinese, Japanese, Korean which indexes bigrams and does some character folding of full-width forms. ICU supports a lot more languages.

Comment: @OkkeKlein Is it the `solr/contrib/analysis-extras/README.txt` file that can be found on GitHub [here](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/tree/master/solr/contrib/analysis-extras) that is being referred to?

Answer (score 12):

Add this at the top of your solrconfig.xml:

```
<config>
  <lib dir="${user.dir}/../contrib/analysis-extras/lucene-libs/" />
  <lib dir="${user.dir}/../contrib/analysis-extras/lib/" />
```

This assumes that you are running from example directory with solr.solr.home set to your instance. Otherwise, just use absolute path to your Solr installation.

You can also copy all those jars into lib directory (under your core, not solr home). But the above is an easier way.

Comment: I would have preferred this way, but it doesn't seem to work for me. I'm using Solr 5.3, and other than copying everything into WEB-INF/lib (of Jetty), it doesn't work.

Comment: UPDATE - nevermind, user error, I was using a relative path that seems incorrect, with an absolute path it works. So just need to find out where my path is wrong.