# search result mismatch in solr 4.7 for spanish characters

Tags: solr

Search is not displaying proper results for Spanish characters like ñ and Ñ in solr 4.7. I have searched in solr help and found that characters are not coming in ASCII range.

How can one map non ASCII chars with ASCII character?
Ex.: In solr index we have chars ñ, Ñ [LATIN CAPITAL LETTER N WITH TILDE] or normal n,N
What filter/token should be used to search with Normal N or Ñ and both should be mapped?

While character Ń [LATIN CAPITAL LETTER N WITH ACUTE] works as an exception.

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22714285/solr-how-to-search-n-and-n-with-normal-char-n-and-vice-verse

Comment: It does not work because characters ñ and Ñ does not come in range of ASCII characters, they are non-ASCII characters.

I want it like, when i search for word Cañen it should provide me results containing words "cañen" as well as "canen".

Answer (score 1):

I tried using [the ICUFoldingFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.ICUFoldingFilterFactory) this works fine with those accents. If this one is tricky to set up, have a look into the SO question [Can not use ICUTokenizerFactory in Solr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14601631/can-not-use-icutokenizerfactory-in-solr)

This analyzer

```xml
<fieldType name="spanish" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.ICUFoldingFilterFactory" />
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

got me these analysis results, the screen-shot is taken from solr-admin

[image: analysis results from solr-admin for Spanish input]